# Windows registry returning incorrect value C++

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

The below code can correctly read Registry values from various different keys, however whenever I try to read a value from a key under `Winlogon` it will either come up as "not found" or it will return a completely wrong value. The code is ran as admin, and compiled with Visual Studio 2017.

```
HKEY registryHandle = NULL;
int registryResult = NULL;

DWORD dataType;
TCHAR dataBuffer[1024] = {};
DWORD bufferSize = sizeof(dataBuffer);

registryResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &registryHandle);
if (registryResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    std::cout << "Error: " << registryResult << std::endl;
    return false;
}

registryResult = RegQueryValueEx(registryHandle, L"LastUsedUsername", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)dataBuffer, &bufferSize);
if (registryResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    std::cout << "Error2: " << registryResult << std::endl;
    return false;
}

std::cout << "Data Size: " << bufferSize << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    if (dataBuffer[i] == NULL) { break; }
    std::cout << (char)dataBuffer[i];
}
std::cin.get();
RegCloseKey(registryHandle);
```

Registry value that I'm trying to read:

[image]

[image]

Below refers to Remy's suggested solution.

RegQueryValueEx Returns a buffer size of 4 with an output of 18754 17236 0 52428

Comment: The `L""` strings suggest you are compiling for `UNICODE`. If `LastUsedUsername` (exists but) contains non-ASCII characters the direct cast `(char)dataBuffer[i]` won't work.

Comment: The Registry API is not going to lie to you.  Either it fails due to lack of permissions, or it fails because the requested value really doesn't exist, or it fails because you give it bad parameters. The `registryResult` will be accurate about the cause of the failure, if there is one. For instance, on my machine, there is no `LastUsedUsername` value present in the `Winlogon` key you are accessing (there is a `DefaultUserName`, though).

Comment: You should be using `std::wcout` instead of `std::cout` for Unicode strings. And there is no reason to use a loop for the output, `RegQueryValueEx()` tells you how many bytes it output, including the null terminator if present.  It is easy enough to write the entire `dataBuffer` as-is to `std::wcout` using its `write()` method, eg: `DWORD len = bufferSize / sizeof(wchar_t); if (len > 0 && dataBuffer[len-1] == 0) { --len; } std::wcout.write(dataBuffer, len);`

Comment: `LastUsedUsername` is that the correct value? It does not exist on my local windows 10 machine. Maybe  you want this: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\LastLoggedOnUser`

Comment: LastUsedUsername is a valid registry value for my system. Also after using the std::wcout.write method the code returns an empty string while the original method of writing to the console returned the an incorrect string of "BT"

Comment: @BobBobby Then please [edit] your question to provide a screenshot of the `regedit.exe` window showing the `LastUsedUsername` value you are trying to read. And a dump of the raw bytes that are actually in your `dataBuffer` after `RegQueryValueEx()` reports success. What is the actual `bufferSize` when `BT` is output? Your loop is ignoring `bufferSize` completely (hence why you should be using `wcout.write()` instead), so it may be outputting random garbage that `RegQueryValueEx()` did not actually intent for you to use (there is reason why the `lpcbData` parameter is an in/out parameter).

Comment: @drescherjm I have the `LastUsedUsername` entry on one of my Win10 machines, though I did not (try to) track down who/what is using it.

Comment: @BobBobby Something does not add up in what you wrote. If the first `WCHAR` is 18754 then outputting it to `wcout` should display the Han character [`U+4942`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/4942/index.htm).But you say the first character is a `B` which is ASCII `0x42`and happens to be the first byte of 18754 (in little endian). At this point it is not clear what code you are running, or what code your comments refer to.

Comment: @dxiv My original code would return a string of "BT" from RegQueryValueEx, however the solution suggested by Remy prints nothing to the console if I supply the value "LastUsedUsername" if I supply a different value such as "Shell" it will return the correct value from the registry.

Comment: @BobBobby Are the values you quote `18754 17236 0 52428` produced by the code which is now in the posted question, and does that code compile cleanly without any warnings? Those numbers look like the ASCII string `"BITC"` (which you then mistakenly display as "BT") *but* that string would/could not be returned by the `W` wide version of `RegQueryValueExW`. As I said, something does not add up.

Comment: Also, @RemyLebeau's code must print *something* when run. So when you say "*prints nothing*" what does that actually mean?

Comment: @dxiv Alright so the my original unchanged code will return the raw bytes 18754 17236 0 0 and when converted to char it produces "BT". In regards to Remy's code it will return the raw bytes 18754 17236 0 52428 which prints out "Data Byte Size: 4
Data Character Length: 2" and nothing else. Each one was supplied with the value "LastUsedUsername"

Comment: @BobBobby what you have shown makes no sense. There is no possible way the Registry value of `Bob` (with or without a null-terminator) causes the output of `RegQueryValueExW()` to be only 4 bytes. It would have to be a minimum of 6-8 bytes since `RegQueryValueExW()` outputs strings using `WCHAR` characters. And decimal 52428 is hex 0xCCCC, which is an indicator that uninitialized stack memory is being accessed, which makes sense if your loop is exceeding the output's null terminator. What EXACTLY is `bufferSize` really being set to? What EXACT BYTES are in `dataBuffer`?

Comment: @BobBobby What you list are certainly not "*raw bytes*" since they are outside the 0-255 range. Assuming you meant `WCHAR` wide characters, instead, then what you have there is the string "䥂䍔". You should see that string if you run it at a Unicode-enabled console with the appropriate font. The "BT" you mention is just an artifact because your code casts (truncates) each wide-char to a narrow-char which happens to match those ASCII characters.

Comment: @RemyLebeau https://i.imgur.com/fKYCh7H.png

Comment: @BobBobby your output is all wrong for the data and code you have shown, so either the code you have shown is not your real code, or there is something seriously corrupted on your system.

Answer (score 2):

You are clearly calling the Unicode version of the Registry functions, so you should be using `WCHAR` instead of `TCHAR` for your data buffer.

And you should not be truncating the characters to `char` at all.  Use `std::wcout` instead of `std::cout` for printing out Unicode strings.  And use the returned `bufferSize` to know how many `WCHAR`s were actually output.  Your printing loop is ignoring the `bufferSize` completely, so it is possible that you are actually printing out random garbage that `RegQueryValueEx()` did not actually intend for you to use (hence why `lpcbData` parameter is an in/**out** parameter, so you know how many bytes are actually valid).

You are also leaking the opened `HKEY` handle if `RegQueryValueEx()` fails.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
HKEY registryHandle;
int registryResult;

registryResult = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon", 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE, &registryHandle);

if (registryResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    std::cout << "Error: " << registryResult << std::endl;
    return false;
}

WCHAR dataBuffer[1024];
DWORD bufferSize = sizeof(dataBuffer);

// TODO: consider using RegGetValueW() instead, which is safer
// when it comes to reading string values from the Registry...
registryResult = RegQueryValueExW(registryHandle, L"LastUsedUsername", NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)dataBuffer, &bufferSize);
RegCloseKey(registryHandle);    

if (registryResult != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    std::cout << "Error2: " << registryResult << std::endl;
    return false;
}

DWORD len = bufferSize / sizeof(WCHAR);
if ((len > 0) && (dataBuffer[len-1] == L'\0')) {
    --len;
}

std::cout << "Data Byte Size: " << bufferSize << std::endl;
std::cout << "Data Character Length: " << len << std::endl;
std::wcout.write(dataBuffer, len);

std::cin.get();
return true;
```

That being said, on my machine, there is no `LastUsedUsername` value in the `Winlogon` key you are accessing, so getting a "not found" error is a very likely possibility.  But you definately need to handle